# Recognizing several digits in an image - CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, optical-character-recognition

I am attempting to build a convolution neural network that will learn to classify images that contain up to three digits. I am currently building my training labels with the following format:

For each image, have 30 classes (0-9 for each potential digit)
Say for example the digits in the image is: **123**

*The label would be:*

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

(Put on separate lines only for ease of reading)

As I very new to the concept of machine learning, I am concerned that this is perhaps a poor approach and I would prefer not to waste time with dead-ends.

I would much prefer to segment the digits into their own images, however as yet the images are somewhat noisy and I am unable to reliably do this.

Any advise on the best way to format my data to achieve this would be *greatly* appreciated. Please do cater to my ignorance when answering and explain any well known methods as clearly as possible.